# memory leaks with function

Tags: memory-leaks

_*_*_Below program should crash when MyClass::processing is called after "delete p" and "p = NULL" but it crashes when "MyClass::a" is tried to access. Why so???

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
        int a;
        void processing()
        {
                cout<<"Processing"<<endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
        MyClass* p(new MyClass);
        MyClass* q = p;
        p->a = 10;
        cout<<"p:: "<<p<<" q:: "<<q<<endl;
        cout<<"p->a"<<p->a<<"q->a"<<q->a<<endl;
        delete p;
        p->processing();   // Watch out! p is now dangling!
        cout<<"\n\nAfter Deletion::"<<endl;
        cout<<"p:: "<<p<<" q:: "<<q<<endl;
        cout<<"p->a"<<p->a<<"q->a"<<q->a<<endl;
        p = NULL;           // p is no longer dangling
        cout<<"\n\nAfter Assigning null"<<endl;
        p->processing();   // Watch out! p is now dangling!
        q->processing();   // Ouch! q is still dangling!
        cout<<"p:: "<<p<<" q:: "<<q<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method after you've deleted the instance is **undefined behaviour**. Anything could happen.

A sample of possible behaviours:

1. You get "lucky": `free` just released the memory but didn't invalidate it. The instance is partially intact, and the call succeeds by accident.
2. `free` overwrites the memory with garbage (or sentinel values), causing you to jump to some crazy address and segfault.
3. `free` deallocates the whole block and you segfault on trying to access `*p`.
4. Some other thread puts the address of `system` in the now-unused block of memory. Your stack happens to contain a pointer to `"rm -rf /"`. Your hard-drive is erased, hilarity ensues.

Never, ever, ever rely on undefined behaviour.